# ndbCluster and Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, database-engine

I'm currently working in a big project where we need to use a ndb cluster engine in an Azure environment (project constraints). I have already read the paper "Set up a MySQL IaaS NDB cluster with 4 nodes on Azure Linux" but i did not manage to find how to access to this offer since cleanDB is passed to PaaS where this process is not possible.

We asked clear DB support team about NDB engine. Unfortunately, their reply was the following:

"We are sorry to say that none of our systems supports NDB at the moment. We provide MySQL DBaaS in cloud infrastructure, our systems are cluster of geo-separated nodes under circular replication."

If someone know how to use this engine in Azure, thanks to give me the solution.

Best regards,
Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

I also read that paper a while ago which was a pretty good walkthrough of how to setup a simple NDB cluster.

I don't think this is an Azure offering. The blog shows how to create Azure instances to setup an NDB Cluster in 4 Azure instances.

So you can always follow the instructions in the blog manually or by
scripting them.

Installing MySQL Cluster on Ubuntu 14.04 is now very easy using the new
APT repo for MySQL. Check the MySQL docs for this.

We also have work in progress on extending the MySQL Cluster
Auto Installer to work more fluently with Cloud instances of
various sorts.

Comment: Thanks Mikael, I know that's really easy in MySQL but the constraint in my project oblige me to use Azure. the issue that the solution shown in the blog is not available since they pass from Iaas to Paas where the unix console is no more accessible (at least in free version).